# AutoMapper - Get error when trying to map two classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I am trying to use AutoMapper to map a DTO to an Entity class but I keep getting an error.

Here is the DTO Class:

```cs
public class Product
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PriceTiers PriceTiers { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the Entity:

```cs
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        PriceTiers = new List<PriceTiers>();
    }

    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PriceTiers> PriceTiers { get; set; }
}
```

Why do I keep getting the following error?

> {"Missing type map configuration or unsupported
> mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nPriceTiers ->
> ICollection`1\r\nWeb.Areas.DEAR.DTOs.PriceTiers ->  System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Web.Areas.DEAR.Data.PriceTiers,
> Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]\r\n\r\n
> Destination Member:\r\nPriceTiers\r\n"}

This is what I have in the Profile class:

```cs
AllowNullCollections = true;
CreateMap<DTOs.Product, Data.Product>();
CreateMap<DTOs.PriceTiers, Data.PriceTiers>();
```

and this is what I use to map the classes:

```cs
var products = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Product>>(result.Products);
```

This is what is in the Program.cs:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfiles).Assembly);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some more research I found out that my mapping profile was not in the right order. These are the changes I made.

```
public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfiles()
        {
            AllowNullCollections = true;

            CreateMap<DTOs.PriceTiers, Data.PriceTiers>();
            CreateMap<DTOs.Product, Data.Product>()
                .ForMember(dto => dto.PriceTiers, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.PriceTiers));
        }        
    }
```

Now it maps perfectly

Answer (score 1):

The exception message is quite clear, the AutoMapper doesn't know how to map the data from `DTOs.PriceTiers` to `ICollection<Data.PriceTiers>`.

---

**Solution 1: Map from `DTOs.PriceTiers` to `ICollection<Data.PriceTiers>`**

I believe that [Custom Type Converters](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html) is what you need.

1. Create Custom Type Converters.

```cs
public class ICollectionDataPriceTiersTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<DTOs.PriceTiers, ICollection<Data.PriceTiers>>
{
    public ICollection<Data.PriceTiers> Convert(DTOs.PriceTiers src, ICollection<Data.PriceTiers> dest, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (src == null)
            return default;
    
        var singleDest = context.Mapper.Map<Data.PriceTiers>(src);
        
        return new List<Data.PriceTiers>
        {
            singleDest
        };
    }
}
```

2. Add to mapping profile.

```cs
CreateMap<DTOs.PriceTiers, ICollection<Data.PriceTiers>>()
    .ConvertUsing<ICollectionDataPriceTiersTypeConverter>();
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rYlaBC)

---

**Solution 2: Map from `ICollection<DTOs.PriceTiers>` to `ICollection<Data.PriceTiers>`**

If the `PriceTiers` in `DTOs.Product` supports multiple items and mapping with *many to many* (to `ICollection<Data.ProductTiers>`), then consider modifying the property as the `ICollection<DTOs.PriceTiers>` type.

```
namespace DTOs
{
    public class Product
    {
        ...
        public ICollection<PriceTiers> PriceTiers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you added "CreateMapper()" method after your configurations?
Try something like that.

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile {
        AllowNullCollections = true;
        CreateMap<DTOs.Product, Data.Product>();
        CreateMap<DTOs.PriceTiers, Data.PriceTiers>();
    }
}
```

After that, on your container service, inject this dependency:

```
var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
});

IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

Comment: I think I covered this in builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfiles).Assembly);